# Which property is sufficient for a Z-Matrix such as it's inverse is pointwise row-diagonally dominant?

Tags: matrices, stochastic-processes

I have a Z-Matrix which is pointwise row-diagonally dominant. (that is: $a_{ii} > a_{ik} \forall k \neq i$).

This matrix is $(I-\alpha A)$, where A is an adjacence matrix of a graph.

Can I say something about the pointwise diagonally dominance of the inverse of this matrix $(I-\alpha A)^{-1}$?

Thanks